# Row number over partition by usage

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

I would like to filter the below table based on the week column, but only when the year week combination is a max.

In the below example I want my output to only select rows with year 2022 and week 1 as that is the latest year week combination.

I am thinking to use a row number over partition by but did not have any success.

```
Car  colour   year   week
aaa  red      2021   52
aaa  black    2021   51
bbb  red      2022   1
bbb  yellow   2022   1
```

Answer (score 2):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY year DESC, week DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Or, in earlier version, you can use:

```sql
SELECT car, colour, year, week
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY year DESC, week DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Car, colour, year, week) AS
SELECT 'aaa', 'red',    2021, 52 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'aaa', 'black',  2021, 51 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 'red',    2022,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 'yellow', 2022,  1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | CAR | COLOUR | YEAR | WEEK |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | bbb | red | 2022 | 1 |
> | bbb | yellow | 2022 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e5ffdfcc57785d0d48d7885ab1357167)*